# IAM Policy for variable Least Access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

So right now we have a bunch of S3 buckets and each bucket has their own lambda function trigger and corresponding IAM roles/policies to be sure that said function can 100% only access that bucket. Is there a way to consolidate down to a single policy for all but still enforce that least-access principle?

So if we end up with 100 buckets, we basically have 100 policies, and 100 roles, and 100 lambdas that are effectively identical, except for the bucket name.

Playing around with conditionals, PrincipalTag and ResourceTag, but can't seem to get it to DWIW.

Comment: can't you just create a policy for that and restrict at the resource level?

Comment: If you tried to do this with a condition based on aws:ResourceTag and aws:PrincipalTag, perhaps you could add what you tried.